# mutex vs. spin lock when thread count = hardware parallelism

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, mutex, spinlock

consider a program with optimal thread count running on dedicated server, so if one thread is locked there're no others (almost) waiting for CPU time. does spin lock provide better performance than mutex in all possible cases in such circumstances?

[EDIT] some explanations: since there's no contention for CPU time between threads, thread can use spin lock w/o any impact on other thread performance. and spin lock doesn't switch to waiting mode that can be heavy enough (at least on windows, idk how it performs on linux)

Comment: Can you explain why do you think spinlock is better than mutex in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your premise isn't very realistic.  Maybe *your* process has the optimum number of threads, the rest to the operating system has many hundred *other* threads.  Some of which might be ready to run and will gladly grab a CPU core when your thread yields.  Furthermore, if the thread is about to be blocked, it is likely to happen because of a lock held by one of the other threads in your process.  Which might release it during the spin-wait time.  The number of threads isn't relevant to that.  It thus still make sense to spin-wait.

Comment: oh, let's split this: 1) system threads will do wake up sometimes, but it's not expected to happen often and to have significant impact on the program that tries to utilize 100% of all cores. 2) not sure I got right the last part: do you mean that spin-wait can react worse on resource unlocking by another thread? can you pls elaborate the whole idea?

Comment: A spin-wait that burns a couple of hundred cycles is useful to avoid burning the thousands of cycles that a context switch will need.  You need to consider, what will make your thread block?  Short from the normal I/O completion waits, which are handled by the OS, the only locks that it can block on are yours.  Spin-waiting them makes sense, regardless of how many threads you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think that spinlock will work better in this case, mutexe's aren't really needed unless you are trying to optimize your code and it depends on varying times for I/O etc... You also made a good point about waiting mode.

Comment: `mutexe's aren't really needed unless you are trying to optimize your code and it depends on varying times for I/O etc`- do you mean described environment or in general?

Comment: I would say in general but there are cases when a spin lock might do just as well if not better.

Answer (score 0):

Spinlock would presumably be more optimal, since there is no transition to kernel.  But the scenario is so contrived that I'd suggest never attempting to apply it to real-life code.

Comment: actually it's not so contrived: web-server, mail-server, media streaming server, game server and so on.

Comment: None of those are ever guaranteed to be in this situation.  To use the counter-argument, in a situation where there is another thread waiting for that CPU, a mutex is almost always going to be more optimal (unless the wait time is extremely short).  A spin lock will consume the CPU and tend to deny a background thread.  That situation is far, far more likely than the one you described in the OP.